# Java rest server: avoid the removal of an item while processing it

Tags: java, rest, arraylist, locking, synchronized

I have an arrayList which is static in the class.

In the beginning of each request, I remove all the obsolete items: `arrayList.entrySet().removeIf(entry -> entry.getValue().isObsolete());`
The removal is done if the item is older than 1 hour. this method is synchronized.

Each API use an item from the list, based on a parameter. If it's in the list, it takes it from there, otherwise it creates a new item and adds it to the list. The API updates the item's data with a certain logic.

How can I avoid the situation where I update a data of an item in API x while API y that has just been called, removes it?

Do I have to synchronized all my APIs? Do I have to lock arrayList object in the beginning of each API? Is there a better/cleaner way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly using a static array list to track objects across service calls is not really a good idea. You might want use something like Terracota or ehCache for maintaining a cache across your service implementations. This will not only free you from worrying about the synchronization issues that you mentioned, but also render scalability , along with performance to your implementation.

Nevertheless still should you intend to follow a static Map implementation; then use Collections.synchronizedList() to obtain a synchronized representation of your map, and use the same in your methods. Following is a sample usage -

```
List<String> cacheList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about ehCache. When using it, I don't need to worry that API x will process an item that API y will delete? it does the "worrying" by itself? I guess it's still need to be static.

Comment: I have added in a sample code for ehCache [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265977/java-serialize-object-to-file-asynchronously/55268922#55268922), you might want to check it out.